# I'm pretty new to JavaScript, HTML and CSS. I'm trying to make a personalized website. What's wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Nothing is showing up at id "nameGreet" when it *should* add the name.

***HTML:***
http://pastebin.com/TmrnYsRz

***JavaScript:***
http://pastebin.com/7ScPRCS9

```js
if (window.confirm("Would you like to enter a name? This gives the site some personalized options?") === true) {
    var name = window.prompt("Name:");
    document.getElementById("nameGreet").innerHTML = "name";
}
```

```html
<h1>George B</h1>
     <p id="nameGreet"> </p>
```

Comment: You need to post the code here, not just as links to pastebin.

Comment: `document.getElementById("nameGreet").innerHTML = name;` without `"`

Comment: Hint: use the Comnsole. Firefox's console says: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null that should lead you to the fact, that the id didn't get read because the browser executes the script first.

Answer (score 1):

Since you quote `"name"`, you're displaying that string literally, instead of using the variable.

```js
if (window.confirm("Would you like to enter a name? This gives the site some personalized options?") === true) {
    var name = window.prompt("Name:");
    document.getElementById("nameGreet").innerHTML = name;
}
```

```html
<h1>George B</h1>
     <p id="nameGreet"> </p>
```

Comment: Thanks! You must have done something else - I didn't have the quotation marks around it before, I added them to test and forgot to remove them, thanks once again!

Comment: It's not working on the application I'm using? (brackets.io)

Comment: Am I supposed to be a mindreader? Post the actual code that doesn't work.

Comment: Have you checked your Javascript console for errors?

Comment: I did post the code that didn't work, it wasn't working on the app I was using, thanks. And yes I have. There's none. Must just be a bug.

Comment: If the code in your application is the same as the code you posted to pastebin except for the quotes, then it should work. Since it doesn't work, it must not be the same. But I can't guess what's different.

Comment: Shouldn't he be using the == operator instead of === in this case? Unless the window.confirm is returning the bool true, his code should never execute, or do I misunderstand how the two work?

Comment: `window.confirm()` returns either `true` or `false`. What do you think it might be returning instead?

Comment: Okay. I thought it was testing for what was in the string or else the user's returned data. I'm still fairly new to Javascript myself.

Comment: @Chris You're confusing `confirm` with `prompt`.